# I need this array solution, any way to do this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Problem:

```
 let arr1 = [{
              min: 10, max: 20
            },
            {
              min: 20, max: 40
            },
            {
              min: 20, max: 40
            }
           ];

let jsonVal = { id: 12345, v1: 5, v2: 10, v3: 9 }
```

Output:

```
let output = [{
              min: 10, max: 20, v1: 5
            },
            {
              min: 20, max: 40, v2: 10
            },
            {
              min: 20, max: 40, v3: 9
            }
           ];
```

jsonVal can increase based on arr1. If arr1 has length of 4 then there will be v1, v2, v3, v4. Also there is no id field to match.
How can i obtain this solution ?

Comment: Are you make sure key of `jsonVal` always is `v`+number?

Comment: yes, it will be always same

Comment: You can use `Object.entries(jsonVal)` to obtain an 2D array of key/value pairs (e.g. [['v1', 5], ['v2', 10], ['v3', 9]]) ten you can use `arr1.map(...)` to obtain the output you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that I can think of is this:

```js
let arr1 = [{
    min: 10,
    max: 20
  },
  {
    min: 20,
    max: 40
  },
  {
    min: 20,
    max: 40
  }
];

let jsonVal = {
  v1: 5,
  v2: 10,
  v3: 9
}
console.log(arr1.map(function (a, i) {
  return {...a, ["v" + (i + 1)]: jsonVal["v" + (i + 1)]}
}));
```

This works only if the `jsonVal` has all the indexes available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Note - this solution depends on jsonVal having the same number of keys as the array and vice versa. Both must have the same length.

```
let arr1 = [
  {
    min: 10,
    max: 20
  },
  {
    min: 20,
    max: 40
  },
  {
    min: 20,
    max: 40
  }
];

let jsonVal = { v1: 5, v2: 10, v3: 9 };
let jsonKeys = Object.keys(jsonVal);

const arr = arr1.map((value, idx) => {
  const currKey = jsonKeys[idx];
  const currVal = jsonVal[currKey];

  return {
    ...value,
    [currKey]: currVal
  };
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr1 = [{min:10,max:20},{min:20,max:40},{min:20,max:40}];

let jsonVal = {
  v1: 5,
  v2: 10,
  v3: 9
};

const result = arr1.map((item, i) => {
  const [key, val] = Object.entries(jsonVal)[i]
  return {
    ...item,
    [key]: val
  };
})

console.log(result);
```